# Oracle Sql Developer Desktop OAUTH

Tags: oracle, oauth, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Is Sql Developer Desktop application supports OAUTH authentication for a Oracle Cloud database?

I would like to authenticate via OAUTH and connect to OCI database with SQL Developer but I cannot find any solution in the Docu of the  SQL Developer.